# Not able to generate the pre signed url for aws s3

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk-js

Im using the following code to generate the pre-signed url using aws sdk in javascript.

```
const aws = require("aws-sdk");
const s3 = new aws.S3();
AWS.config.update({
    accessKeyId: "generated access key",
    secretAccessKey: "generated secret key"
})

const s3_param = {
    Bucket: "bucket-name",
    Key: "file-name"
}

const signedUrl = s3.getSignedUrl("putObject", s3_param);
console.log(signedUrl);
```

This  is giving me `undefined`. If I pass the callback as the 3ed argument, it is not executing the callback at all. What am I missing here?

Edit

Uninstalling the `aws-sdk` package and installing it again worked for me. Not sure why.

Comment: You have created a variable called `s3_param`, but in the call to `getSignedUrl()`, it is referring to `s3_params`. These are different variable names.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein just a typo here. my bad.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you created env. file in the root directory of your project.Then add environment-specific variables for host, user, and password.

```
require('dotenv').load();
require('dotenv').config();
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var credentials = {
    accessKeyId: process.env.S3_ACCESS_KEY,
    secretAccessKey : process.env.S3_SECRET_KEY
};
AWS.config.update({credentials: credentials, region: 'eu-central-1'});
var s3 = new AWS.S3();

var presignedGETURL = s3.getSignedUrl('getObject', {
    Bucket: 'presignedurldemo',
    Key: 'ivana.jpg', 
    Expires: 60
});
```

This should work for creating a GET URL using the AWS S3 class.

Comment: I don't know what happened but uninstalling the `aws-sdk` package and installing it again worked for me. Thanks for the answer though.